# What is the average maximum value of a set of random numbers?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics, average, geometric-probability

Let $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_{10}$ be ten randomly chosen real numbers in the interval [0,1].

Let $m$ be the maximal value out of these 10 numbers.

What is the expected value of $m$?

(i.e. If i had $n$ sets of 10 numbers and took the maximum $m$ for each set and averaged the values of all the $m$'s, what would this value become as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: While true that doesn't really matter here @Masacroso.  There exists a distribution of the maximal values of that sample.

Comment: If $a_\imath$ are independent, uniformly distributed (are they?) then the answer is $10 \over 11$, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150586/expected-value-of-max-of-iid-variables .

Comment: Note the usual confusion, addressed in the comment above: "randomly chosen" does not really mean *anything* mathematically, what you mean seems to be "chosen independently and **uniformly** at random." (A probability distribution that puts mass $1$ on $\{1\}$ is still a valid probability distribution over $[0,1]$, but choosing 10 numbers "randomly" from it will give you $1$ ten times, almost surely.)

Comment: @ClementC. All true, and it is good to encourage precision, but isn't the uniform distribution the obvious one to use if none is mentioned?

Comment: It is -- but between the independence and the uniformity, it's always good to be precise.