# Finding the expectation of $\hat \theta$, if $\theta = \max(X_1, ..., X_n)$

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I am trying to make $\hat \theta$ an unbiased estimator for a uniform distribution on $(0, \theta)$. So I am given the fact that $\hat \theta$ is the MLE for $\theta$, but I need to show that if I choose $c_1$, then the estimator becomes unbiased. What gets me stuck is the fact that $\hat \theta = \max(X_1, ..., X_n)$.

Basically, how do I deal with the "max" part of the problem given that I want to show that $\hat \theta$ can be unbiased if we choose $c_1$ such that $E[\hat\theta]$ = $\theta$.

ie. I need to find $c_1$ such that $\hat \theta = c_1 \max(X_1, ..., X_n)$ such that $\hat \theta$ is unbiased (aka $E(\hat \theta) = \theta)$

Thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150586/expected-value-of-max-of-iid-variables

Comment: @angryavian Thank you so much, that really helped!

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes, thank you so much! I can solve the question now :D